# Jquery Slidedown moves other div down

Tags: jquery, css, slideup

I am trying to position div absolute with css. I have 2 divs where I am using jquery slide down and slide up. If one div slides down, other div is also disturbed with this code [`here`](http://jsfiddle.net/K2ndZ/1/).

Could soe one suggest me aproach to stop second div sliding when mouse over on first div and vice versa.

Comment: Hey buddy, can u create a jsfiddle for this

Comment: check out my answer i've change some of your code and it's work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out this link here is http://jsfiddle.net/sarfarazdesigner/K2ndZ/5/
for this you have to change some code of your 
**this is css**

```
.combobox {cursor:pointer;display:inline-block; position:relative;}
.combobox .selector {position:relative; float:left; }
.combobox .selector p{border:1px solid #cccccc;padding: 2px 5px;}
.combobox ul {padding:0;margin:0;display:inline-block;border:1px solid #eeeeee;background-color:#cccccc;}
.combobox li {padding: 2px 5px}
```

**this is html**

```
<div class="combobox">
    <div class="selector">
        <p>Please select</p>
        <ul>
            <li>Option 1</li>
            <li>Option 2</li>
            <li>Option 3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>


    <div class="selector">
        <p>Please select</p>
        <ul>
            <li>Option 1</li>
            <li>Option 2</li>
            <li>Option 3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**and this is jQuery part**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.combobox ul').hide();
    $('.combobox p').hover(
        function(){
            console.log(this);
            $(this).next('ul').stop().slideDown();
        },
        function(){
            $(this).next('ul').stop().slideUp();
        }
    );
    $('.combobox li').click(function(){
        $(this).parents('.combobox').find('.selector').text($(this).text());
    });
});
```

**updated link according to you**

http://jsfiddle.net/sarfarazdesigner/K2ndZ/7/

Comment: Hi Mechanic,
http://jsfiddle.net/K2ndZ/6/ I am looking for this scenario where the below dropdown is moving down. I want first dropdown values on top of second and want to see that second dropdown will not move.

Comment: it's simple give `position absolute` to `ul` and `z-index` to above of that `div` it works

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sarfarazdesigner/K2ndZ/7/ go through this link i update it or check my updated answer

Comment: Hi Mechanic,
I am unable to set dropdown items very close to "Please Select". Distance between Please select and dropdown items is more in Internet explorer. Do we have some option to bind items to dropdown closely and exactly?

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/K2ndZ/3/

I did changes only in `.combobox {cursor:pointer;float:left; margin-left:10px;}`